# Should I use Rufus or Etcher to duel boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Tags: rufus

I don't know which one to use, Rufus or Etcher. Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

I currently use 18.10 and Windows 10 as dual boot. I first installed Windows 10 used Rufus to create a bootable USB for 18.10 and then installed Ubuntu. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: You are welcome :)